# Material design components button global theme overriding broken

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I want to simply apply styling to all buttons on a theme level like this

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...    
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DefaultButton</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whatever</item>
</style>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addChannelButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Add room" />
```

Why doesnt this work? It would in appcompat

// If I use `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`, then it works

Answer (score 8):

You should be setting `materialButtonStyle` instead of `buttonStyle` in your theme.

Comment: works, however it now ignores my background setting (custom shape drawable), any way for me to override everything via materialButtonStyle? (when using bridge theme and buttonStyle, the background works)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Theme.MaterialComponents`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) theme defining the [**`materialButtonStyle`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#theming-all-instances-of-one-component) attribute.

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ....

    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonTheme</item>
  </style>
```

In this way you can customize the theme of all the buttons in your app.
Also starting from version 1.1.0 of the material library you can override the theme attributes from the default style using the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
  <style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ButtonStyleTextColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonStyleTextColor">
    <!-- For filled buttons, your theme's colorPrimary provides the default background color of the component, and -->
    <!--the text color is colorOnPrimary -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

  </style>
```

Currently it requires version **1.1.0** of material components for android library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with v1.0.0-alpha06? There has been some progress since v1.0.0 which may have addressed what you're seeing.

#### 1.1.0-alpha02

- Shape Theming: FloatingActionButton, MaterialButton, Chip, MaterialCardView, BottomSheet, & TextInputLayout updated to use the new Material shape system

#### 1.1.0-alpha06

- Implement Shapeable interface in MaterialButton

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases

Answer (score 0):

Use `materialButtonStyle` and use `MaterialButton` instead of `Button`